# How to run process on multiple records?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I want to create an on-demand process of some kind in Dynamics CRM 2013 that will run on multiple records of the same type. The process will create an equal number of records of another type, and all will relate to the same parent record. I can imagine how a workflow would be used to create the new child records but I am not sure how I could create the parent record and associate it with the child records.

Comment: What is the aim of the record creation? IF you are trying to create a report you could create a XML/CSV download instead?

Comment: The idea is that the existing records are services (custom, not the built-in Service entity), and this process will convert each selected service into a work order item instance. The parent record would be the overall work order.

Comment: To clarify, you want to run the workflow on selected services and for each service it would create a work order associated with many work order items then set the service as the parent of the work order?

Comment: No, the process would pull field values from the selected services into new work order items, which would be parented by a new work order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're running on multiple records, then I presume your are starting from a gridview of some sort.  If that's the case, then the solution is easy.  Just create a custom ribbon button that accepts the selected records as a parameter, and runs a custom javascript.  That will accomplish what you need in a nice elegant solution.

Because it's running javascript, you will have full control to be able to do everything you need.  One of the features of ribbon buttons, is they can receive the selected records in a parameter as an array.
But if you don't want to do all the work in javascript, you can have the script pass the parameters to a custom Workflow or Action.

As its already been mentioned, a workflow won't be able to do this alone, because it can only run on a single record, and cannot accept multiple records as an input parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Jason I think the point here is to automate the process.  Lee you are correct in your assessment that creating the work order with a workflow step is easy to do while creating the child work order items is either difficult or impossible.  Even if you managed to hack this together with several workflows triggered by different events during the process the end result would be a UX/maintenance nightmare.

The simplest and best solution is to have piece of plugin logic that you trigger with your workflow.  This plugin code would create a new work order and associated work order items based on the context of the service you run the workflow against.  If you would like for this action to be triggered by a database operation instead of manually triggered this would be simple to do as well.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't going to be able to do this via a CRM dialog because it can only run against one record. You can accomplish this fairly easily by leveraging existing CRM functionality:

1. If it doesn't already exist, create a field in your service entity (the *Work Order Item*) called `new_MasterWorkOrder` (or something similar) which is link to a *Master Work Order* entity.
2. Create your master record - this would be your *Overall Work Order*.
3. From your *Work Order Item* record entry listing, select all the items you want to add to the *Master Work Order* record created in the previous step. Alternately, you could use an Advanced Find to locate the target records.
4. Click the Edit button to initiate the CRM bulk/multi-record edit form.
5. In the `new_MasterWorkOrder` field, select the *Overall Work Order* previously created.
6. Save.

Once the process complete, all of the *Work Order Items* you selected will now be linked to your *Overall Work Order*.

It sounds like you might a need a step before this to create a *Work Order Item* from selected *Service* entities. You should be able to accomplish this easily by having a workflow which runs takes in a *Service* entity as a parameter and builds a *Work Order Item* from it. Once you have these built you can link them to an *Overall Work Order* using the process above.